# Azure App Service Could not load file or assembly

Tags: azure-web-app-service, sitecore9

I am trying to stand up a sitecore site inside a fresh app service in Azure. This already works in our production Azure account, but we would like to see how to set it up from scratch.

The build and deploy succeed in pushing it out to the app service, however, I am getting:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.Cors, Version=5.2.3.0

and no further information. I verified that system.web.http.dll is present in the bin folder. I read in some other articles that sometimes the wrong version could cause issues but this works on my work machine. Is there another step I need to do to make this work in an app service? Some configuration change, maybe?

Comment: What was your solution?

Comment: I walked away... We had an outside vendor come and set it up. They used pre-made scripts from SC and ran them in Powershell. Voila.

Comment: There are, apparently, many dlls that do not get pushed by publish. They have to be placed there by the installer.

Answer (score 1):

The dll is missing in the published (deployed environment). That is the reason why it is working in the local i.e. Visual Studio but not in the Azure Website Environment.

Just do Copy Local = true in the properties for the assembly(**System.Web.Http.Cors**) and then do a redeploy, it should work fine.

If Copy Local is already set to true and you cannot update the WebApi because of dependencies, there is that trick to set Copy Local to false, build, then set Copy Local back to true and build.

Comment: No, no progress so far.